# What Would Cause This Error for ASP.NET Core MVC Bot-based Requests: `Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access`?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am experiencing a weird set of exceptions in my production environment, occurring with a ASP.NET Core MVC-based .NET7 application.

Here is an instance of what I see in [my Seq logs](https://datalust.co/), occurring in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` source contexts:

[image]

Notice that two of them share the same `ConnectionId` and `RequestId`, while all share the same `RequestId`.  Additionally, this only appears to occur with user agents that have a bot-based identifier.  For instance, the above has the following user agent, denoting a Google Bot for images:

```
Googlebot-Image/1.0
```

*I do not see these exceptions with normal human-based browsing.*

The problem appears to occur with accessing the `ITempDataDictionary`.
Please note that they do not involve any of my custom code which makes this difficult to track down.

I will paste the timestamps, logging sources, and stack traces in the order they appear from above:

```
Time: 22 Oct 2023 23:18:36.032
Source: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer:
Stack Trace:
System.InvalidOperationException: Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
   at ref TValue System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.FindValue(TKey key)
   at bool System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
   at ITempDataDictionary Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(HttpContext context)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.SaveTempData(IActionResult result, ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory, IList<IFilterMetadata> filters, HttpContext httpContext)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()+Awaited(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()+Awaited(?)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()+Awaited(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()+Logged(?) x 2
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)+AwaitRequestTask(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)+Awaited(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)+Awaited(?)
   at async Task<bool> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<TContext>.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

```
Time: 22 Oct 2023 23:18:36.013
Source: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
Stack Trace:
System.InvalidOperationException: Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
   at ref TValue System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.FindValue(TKey key)
   at bool System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
   at ITempDataDictionary Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(HttpContext context)
   at object Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()+Awaited(?)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()+Logged(?) x 2
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)+AwaitRequestTask(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
```

```
Time: 22 Oct 2023 23:18:35.994
Source: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
Stack Trace: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
   at ref TValue System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.FindValue(TKey key)
   at bool System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
   at ITempDataDictionary Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(HttpContext context)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.SaveTempData(IActionResult result, ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory, IList<IFilterMetadata> filters, HttpContext httpContext)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()+Awaited(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()+Awaited(?)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()+Awaited(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()+Logged(?) x 2
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)+AwaitRequestTask(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)+Awaited(?)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)+Awaited(?)
   at async Task<bool> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<TContext>.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

```
Time: 22 Oct 2023 23:18:35.977
Source: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer
Stack Trace:
System.InvalidOperationException: Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
   at ref TValue System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.FindValue(TKey key)
   at bool System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
   at ITempDataDictionary Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(HttpContext context)
   at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.SaveTempData(IActionResult result, ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory, IList<IFilterMetadata> filters, HttpContext httpContext)
   at Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.OnStarting(HttpContext httpContext)
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.FireOnStarting()
```

It is unclear to me what is occurring to make this happen, and why it only occurs with bot-based requests.

Any assistance in helping to track down this exception with additional logging or troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you are handling some requests using parallelism (i.e., several threads per request) or maybe you are missing `await` somewhere?

Comment: Anything is possible here @GuruStron which is what I would like to explore.  I have both Visual Studio and ReSharper analysis on my solution which both complain when there is a missing `await`, so I do not think that is the culprit (but who knows).  The challenging issue is that this is not obviously in my code and would like to track it down via logging or equivalent.

Comment: It appears that there's a race condition or concurrent access to an underlying `Dictionary` used by the `ITempDataDictionary`. This can be problematic as `Dictionary` is not thread-safe. consider switching to `ConcurrentDictionary` which is thread-safe. Implement more detailed logging, specifically around areas where `ITempDataDictionary` is accessed or modified. Monitor and log the number of concurrent requests from bots. Try to reproduce the issue in local machine. Use some tool to simulate rapid and concurrent requests similar to bots.

Comment: Indeed I have tried to emulate this locally in my development environment @JalpaPanchal but it does not reproduce there.  `ITempDataDictionary` is used by MVC and is not configured in any way in my custom code.  In fact. this is a Blazor server-side application this is occurring in and MVC is the hosted context of this.

As for additional/detailed logging, that is exactly what I am requesting here in my question, so any further suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Program.cs: `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); builder.Logging.AddConsole();builder.Logging.AddDebug();builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);  var app = builder.Build();`
Anywhere you need logging in your application (Controllers, Services, etc.), use Dependency Injection to get an instance of `ILogger<YourClassType>`.Add detailed logging around the areas you suspect might be causing issues, like before and after accessing `ITempDataDictionary`. To get more detailed logs from ASP.NET Core itself, set      builder.Logging.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Trace);

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @JalpaPanchal, I am familiar with turning on the firehose so to speak with Trace level.  Ideally, I would need something a little more exact for this scenario to reduce the amount of pressure this would apply to my prod logging.  Note that I am not using tempdata anywhere in my application so it is unclear to me how this is getting called.  That is, I do not have any suspected areas where this is called as my application is Blazor and does not actively invoke MVC components, nor do I make use of TempData anywhere in my application.  I hope that further clarifies.

Comment: The ITempDataDictionary "Represents a set of data that persists only from one request to the next." This is where you find your hint. If this only persists when using bots, then maybe you are configuring the bots incorrectly, since they then have the same ConnectionID. If it is the same connection, maybe it is trying to access the same dictionary instance that is still in memory, as the connection is not closed(?).
My guess is, that either you are setting up async bots with completely the same access, or you are not closing some connection after it is used.

Comment: Thank you for your input @RatzMouze ... can you explain a bit more about what you mean by configuring bots? To be certain these are external bots and I have no control over how they are configured, only what content they can access via robots.txt file. I can confirm that these pages are allowed pages by the bots via this file (product information pages). Also, to be certain, the request/connection is the same because of the particular request in this case. Another instance of this error will have a different  set of IDs, but values will be shared as above, denoting access in the same request.

Comment: Hi. Any success? I have the same issue. Impossible to reproduce locally, but looks like this error occurs when application starts after some inactivity (may be IOC initialization step). I saw this error couple times myself in DEV server. First web request - error, and second the same - no error. And I can't understand why I have only one API point where I see this error. Possible some internal conflict on initialize DB, Elastic, XRAY... I still confused during couple days...

Comment: I am glad I am not the only one experiencing this @PavelSamoylenko.  I ended up giving up and using my suggested `ConcurrentItemsMiddleware` middleware found here, which doesn't really explain why this is happening, but does provide a workaround for now: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50284#issuecomment-1835918445 As you can see, I reported this issue to ASP.NET Core team but it's been tough getting assistance as it's so difficult to reproduce.  Please feel free to add to the discussion there.

Answer (score -1):

The exceptions you're seeing are related to the `ITempDataDictionary` in ASP.NET Core MVC. `ITempDataDictionary` is a dictionary that is used to store data that is kept for the duration of a single HTTP request. It is typically used to pass data from the controller to the view. However, it seems like there is a concurrent update being performed on this collection, which is causing the state of the collection to become corrupted.

The `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message

> Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive
> access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and
> corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.

is thrown when you try to modify a collection while it is being enumerated over, or when two threads are trying to modify the collection at the same time. This is not allowed because it can lead to unpredictable results.

The fact that these exceptions only occur with bot-based user agents could be due to the way these bots are making requests to your application. Bots can make requests at a much faster rate than a human user, which could lead to concurrent modifications of the `ITempDataDictionary`.

To resolve this issue, you might want to consider the following steps:

Synchronize access to the `ITempDataDictionary`: You could use a lock to ensure that only one thread can access the `ITempDataDictionary` at a time. This can be done using the lock statement in C#. However, this could potentially lead to performance issues if the lock is held for a long time.
Use a concurrent collection: If possible, consider using a concurrent collection instead of `ITempDataDictionary`. .NET provides several concurrent collections that are safe to use from multiple threads, such as `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.
Limit the rate of requests from bots: If the issue is being caused by bots making requests too quickly, you could consider implementing some rate limiting on your application. This would allow you to limit the number of requests that a bot can make in a given time period.
Improve error handling: You can improve the error handling in your application by implementing a global exception handling middleware. This middleware can catch any exceptions that are thrown during the request pipeline and handle them consistently. This can help to prevent the application from crashing when an exception occurs, and can also make it easier to diagnose and fix issues.

Here is an example of how you could implement a global exception handling middleware in your application:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
   private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

   public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
   {
       _next = next;
   }

   public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   {
       try
       {
           await _next(context);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
       }
   }

   private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
   {
       context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
       context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

       return context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails()
       {
           StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
           Message = "Internal Server Error from the custom middleware."
       }.ToString());
   }
}
```

This middleware can be registered in your `Startup.cs` file like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
   else
   {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
       app.UseHsts();
   }

   app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

   // Other middleware...
}
```

[Handling and throwing exceptions in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/)

[TempDataDictionary Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.tempdatadictionary?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @DepletedKnowledge.  That is a good general overview of the issue, but it does not help determine the root cause of the issue which would continue to persist if I wrapped it in a middleware.  Specifically, if two threads are accessing this component concurrently, how would I better determine how this is occurring?  I like the middleware approach but what I need is some logging to point me how it is being accessed on two different threads concurrently so that I can further diagnose/mitigate it.  Thank you for any further assistance.

Comment: Have you tried to diagnose the issue of concurrent access to the ITempDataDictionary, you can use ASP.NET Core's built-in logging mechanism? This will allow you to log detailed information about the requests that are causing the exceptions, including the user agent, the request path, and the time of the request. I can edit the question with some examples if you haven't yet.

Comment: That is more along the lines of what I am thinking @DepletedKnowledge.  However, please keep in mind that the request path, user agent, and even the request itself are all the same as denoted in my original post.  That is, the same request is somehow accessing this component -- which is scoped to the request itself -- with different threads and causing this error.  If there is some way to determine how this is getting called from different threads am all for hearing more. 